# Reactjs skip or change index value on Array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My problem is that I'm trying to change the index value when a react element was not created when using the map function.

My current(non working code):

```
{this.state.images.map(function (image, index) {
    if(!image.cover_photo){
        return <OutfitImage image={image} key={index} id={index} onRemoveImage={this.removeImage} onSetCoverPhoto={this.setCoverPhoto} />;
    }else{
        index--;
    }
}.bind(this))}
```

This code is located within the return () block of my components' render function.

The reason I want to do this, is because I'm using the index value as an id for each element that is created. This id helps me determine how many elements that there are everytime an element is created.
The purpose of this, is that I want to add a "clearfix" after every 4rth element.

Simple solution: I could create a new array of images, leaving the one I don't need out, thus the index will always be correct.

However I'm looking for an alternative solution, that doesn't require that I change the original array or create a new array beforehand.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to do here....are you just trying to remove an item from the array?

Comment: how about filtering the array first? `images.filter(i => i.cover_photo).map( ... )`

Comment: @erichardson30 I thought that goes without saying, but yes I'm removing an item. There's no problem in removing it, but the index will still update, and thus pass wrong information to the subsequent react elements. Let's say the item I want to remove is number [1] in an array with a length of 3. The third and last element will then have the index 2, but I want it to have index 1, indicating that there are now 2 elements, and so forth.

Comment: @azium exactly what I was looking for! thanks :) If you post an answer, I'll gladly accept it.